# Returning unique_ptr from std::for_each + lambda functions

Tags: c++, vector, foreach, bitmap, c++17

I am facing a problem with returning std::moved unique_pointers to a lambda. Once I have moved the pointer to the lambda function how do I take the ownership back from the lambda?

In the following code I am demonstrating my problem. I have taken a snipped out from code-base and moved everything to main to explain the problem better. First question is marked as "QUESTION 1" - where I want to understand if I am correct in using (*v) for accessing my vector.

The code creates a vector of few numbers, and then iterates over the vector to mark the bits in the bitmap. I think the bits are marked correctly as I am able to print them in the lambda itself. After marking the bits, I want the ownership back. How do I do it? I need to return the bitmap pointer to the caller function.

How to take the ownership back in a STANDARD way from a lambda rather than hacking around the passed unique_ptr or avoiding moving the pointer to lambda. Does cpp17 support this?

Compile the code with g++ -std=c++17

```
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main () {

  int increments = 10;
  int numberOfElements = 10;

  /* Create the vector */
  auto v = std::make_unique<std::vector<int>>(std::vector<int> (numberOfElements));

  /* QUESTION 1 - is (*v) the right way to access it or there is a better way. */
  std::generate((*v).begin(), (*v).end(), [n=0, increments]() mutable { n = n + increments; return n;});

  /* Print the generated elements */
  std::cout << "\nPrinting the generated elements ";
  std::for_each((*v).begin(), (*v).end(), [](int n) { std::cout<<" " << n;});


  /* Int find the maximum element */
  int maxElement = *(std::max_element((*v).begin(), (*v).end()));
  /* Making a bitmap of the elements */

  std::cout << "\nPrinting the maxElement " << maxElement;
  auto bitmap = std::make_unique<std::vector <bool>> (std::vector<bool>(maxElement + 1));

  /* Now setting all the elements in the vector to true in the bitmap. */

  for_each((*v).begin(), (*v).end(), [bmap = std::move(bitmap)](int n) { 
                                        (*bmap).at(n) = true; 

                                        if ((*bmap).at(n) == true) { 
                                          std::cout << "\nBit "<< n <<" marked";
                                        }
                                      });

  /******************************************************* 
   * Question 2 : I now need the ownership of bitmap back.
   * How to do it ?. Bitmap is now null after moving it to the lambda.
   */
  if (bitmap) {
    std::cout << "\nafter reset, ptr is not NULL ";
  } else if (bitmap == nullptr) {
    std::cout << "\nbitmap is null";
  }

}
```

Comment: Why are you moving the map into the lambda to begin with?

Comment: On a bit of rethinking about the code, I think an even better question is why have a `unique_ptr` to a `vector` in the first place? A scoped pointer to a `vector` seems redundant. `vector` IS a scoped pointer.

Comment: @StoryTeller I need to return the bitmap to the caller function later on, where I want to give the ownership to the caller. For this I used a unique_ptr. I have copied a part of the code to the main function.

Comment: @user4581301 - I have to return the vector and the bitmap pointer to the caller back and transfer the ownership to the caller. This function is just for demonstration of the problem.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. It seems to me like cargo-cult programming, I'm afraid. I don't see a reason for quite a few of the copies you made. Maybe your example simplifies the issue too much, I dunno.

Comment: It is very easy to return a `vector`. If RVO doesn't make it no more expensive than copying a couple pointers, you can `std::move` it. Save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: `(*v).begin()` can be replaced by `v->begin()`.

Comment: @StoryTeller the question is mostly directed towards having a **standard** way of taking back the ownership of the pointer. I accept that it is a bit of cargo-cult because I am still experimenting and learning and thus I posted the question. Let us say that in the legacy code I get this vector which is pointed to by a unique_ptr, then what is the best way to initialize a bitmap by using lambda functions OR we cannot do this using lambda function ? Is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> QUESTION 1 - is (*v) the right way to access it or there is a better way.

Alternative is using `->`, so `v->begin()` instead of `(*v).begin()`.
but it is strange to use `unique_ptr` for `vector`.
You might simply do:

```
std::vector<int> v(numberOfElements);

std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(),
              [n=0, increments]() mutable { n = n + increments; return n;});

std::cout << "\nPrinting the generated elements ";
for (int e : v) { std::cout << " " << e; };

int maxElement = *std::max_element(v.begin(), v.end());

// ...
```

> Question 2 : I now need the ownership of bitmap back. How to do it ?

You cannot do it with lambda, in your case capturing by reference do the job (even if the lambda would own the vector, the `for_each` "block" doesn't):

```
std::vector<bool> bitmap(maxElement + 1);

for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [&bmap](int n) { 
                                 bmap.at(n) = true;
                                 std::cout << "\nBit "<< n <<" marked";
                             });
assert(!bitmap.empty());
if (bitmap.empty()) {
    std::cout << "\nbitmap is empty";
} else if (bitmap == nullptr) {
    std::cout << "\nbitmap is NOT empty";
}
```

If you replace your lambda with your own functor, you might do something like

```
class MyMarker
{
public:
    MyMarker(std::vector<bool>&& bitmap) : bitmap(std::move(bitmap)) {}

    MyMarker(const MyMarker&) = delete;
    MyMarker& operator =(const MyMarker&) = delete;

    void operator() (int n) const
    {
        bitmap.at(n) = true;
        std::cout << "\nBit "<< n <<" marked";
    }

    std::vector<bool> TakeBack() { return std::move(bitmap); }

private:
    std::vector<bool> bitmap;
};
```

and then:

```
std::vector<bool> bitmap(maxElement + 1);
MyMarker myMarker(std::move(bitmap));
assert(bitmap.empty());

std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), myMarker);
bitmap = myMarker.TakeBack();
assert(!bitmap.empty());
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. I got to learn a lot. This solves my queries.

Comment: I have a small doubt on your comment "your case capturing by reference do the job " - is this a standard way of doing it. Because if we are passing by reference - then we are creating another reference to the same pointer - whereas the unique_ptr will not know about it. Thus the whole idea of having a unique_pointer gets dropped. In case of this program, this is not that bad as this is a sequential code, but in case of a multi threaded application - I think we are doing something fundamentally wrong. Let me know if I am wrong, I just want to understand this completely.

Comment: A reference should have a shorter life time that the object it refers to. As lambda is only used locally, you can guaranty the lifetime of objects.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.